# R: If i is true then assign string to matrix

Tags: r, for-loop

I can't get a for loop to assign the string 'NA' when none of the other conditions are met.

This is what I've tried...

```
Height <- c(1.6,3.4,0.42,n/a, 0.5,n/a,1.5,0,n/a,22.0)
Height <- matrix(Height)  

h_cat <- matrix(, nrow = length(Height), ncol = 1)
for (i in 1:length(Height)){
  if (Height[i]==0)
    h_cat[i] <- 'NA'
  if (Height[i]>0 & Height[i]<2)
    print(Height[i])
    h_cat[i] <- '0-2 m'
    #print(h_cat[i])
  if (Height[i]>=2 & Height[i]<5)
    h_cat[i] <- '2-5 m'
  if (Height[i]>=5 & Height[i]<10)
    h_cat[i] <- '5-10 m'
  if (Height[i]>=10)
    h_cat[i] <- '>10 m'
  else
    h_cat[i] <- 'NA'
}
```

I had a go with is.na() but no luck either.

Update

Sorry that was rushed. Data added.

Comment: Please share some data... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: You should look into the `cut` function

Comment: `h_cat` is a `matrix`, it has row and column numbers. It should be indexed as `h_cat[i, 1]`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas no luck with that either

Comment: You obviously didn't try that code because `n/a` would trigger an error.

Comment: This is strange code for R which generally tries to avoid control structures like that, but you might just try  `h_cat <- Height` and then `h_cat[Height==0] <- NA` etc though I agree that cut is good or even better maybe use a hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main problems with the current code.

1. First can be exemplified by `NA == 0`, which returns NA. Thus you can only use the `if` function on the non-NA entries: `which(!is.na(Height))`.
2. The logic of your `if-else` construction is not working as what seems to be the intention.

The below I believe achieves your intentions:

```
# Data needs to be numeric to check with ">"
Height[Height == "n/a", ] <- NA
Height <- as.numeric(Height)

h_cat <- matrix(, nrow = length(Height), ncol = 1)

# Can't have NA in logical tests
non_na_entries <- which(!is.na(Height))
for (i in non_na_entries) {
  if (Height[i] == 0) {
    h_cat[i] <- NA
  } else if (Height[i] > 0 & Height[i] < 2) {
    h_cat[i] <- '0-2 m'
  } else if (Height[i] >= 2 & Height[i] < 5) {
    h_cat[i] <- '2-5 m'
  } else if (Height[i] >= 5 & Height[i] < 10) {
    h_cat[i] <- '5-10 m'
  } else if (Height[i] >= 10) {
    h_cat[i] <- '>10 m'
  } else
    h_cat[i] <- NA
}

    h_cat

     [,1]   
 [1,] "0-2 m"
 [2,] "2-5 m"
 [3,] "0-2 m"
 [4,] NA     
 [5,] "0-2 m"
 [6,] NA     
 [7,] "0-2 m"
 [8,] NA     
 [9,] NA     
[10,] ">10 m"
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code. Two of them were addressed by snoram. You need to substitute `NA` for `'n/a'`, and you don't need `Height` to be a `matrix`. To make the code that follows a complete answer, I'll repeat the `NA` part.

```
Height <- c(1.6,3.4,0.42,n/a, 0.5,n/a,1.5,0,n/a,22.0)
Height[Height == "n/a"] <- NA
```

Now, an alternative to a complicated `if/else` is, like many have said, `cut`. Since it returns an object of class `factor` we'll need to recode its return value. To do that, I'll use a function from package `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

h_cat <- cut(Height, c(0, 2, 5, 10, Inf))
h_cat[Height == 0] <- NA
h_cat <- recode_factor(h_cat,
                 '(0,2]' = '0-2 m',
                 '(2,5]' = '2-5 m',
                 '(5,10]' = '5-10 m',
                 '(10,Inf]' = '>10 m')
h_cat <- matrix(as.character(h_cat), ncol = 1)
h_cat
```

I believe that this is much simpler and readable. Neater. If you ever have to come back to this code in the future, you'll probably find it much easier to maintain.